# Navigate Form Controls with VoiceOver by pressing TAB

Tags: macos, voiceover

I'm new to OS X as well as Voice Over. In web applications you can navigate the elements with a screen reader just by pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

I need the same functionality with VoiceOver for OS X so that I can press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to navigate the form controls. Is it possible?

Comment: Wouldn't your users expect it to behave like the other native apps they are using or do you feel that "behave as a webpage" is what they'd expect?

Comment: Are you talking about pressing TAB to navigate in a native app or in a web site?